# On the cardinality of quotient set

Tags: set-theory

I have read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2684569/525789) that a quotient set may have a cardinality strictly greater of the starting set in ZF.
I would to know if we add to ZF the axiom "for every set $X$ and equivalence relation $\thicksim$ on $X$, we have $|X/\thicksim|\leq|X|$".
I was wondering what theory we obtain, certainly it is strictly stronger than ZF and weaker than ZFC, but is strictly weaker than ZFC or is equivalent?
I was looking to proof that is equivalent considering a nonempty family $\{X_i|i\in I\}$ of nonempty set and i considered the relation on the product $X=\prod\{X_i|i\in I\}$ fixed a factor $X_j$, and let $p_j$ the projection, $(x_i)\thicksim(y_i)$ iff $x_j=y_j$, my idea was that the quotient $X/\thicksim$ is substantially $X_j$ (in particular they are in bijection) but now i think this doesn't work.

Comment: I've closed as a duplicate of not quite that, but close enough question, and the answer I posted there should lead you on a journey through other reading materials. The principle you refer to is known as The Partition Principle, and I have written extensively about it on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: (And see [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2158581) for a complete list of stuff linked to that question, which also includes other questions and answers which were posted later on.)